# Implement Transposition cipher in c++

Tags: c++, cryptography, c++14

I try to implement the encryption by [Columnar transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Columnar_transposition).

**Input**: key_secret and Text_to_encrypt, both of them are in lower.

**Output**: encrypted_text.

The code works fine but I have some questions:

- it warns: "Function 'begin' could not be resolved", Function 'end' could not be resolved, Function 'copy_if' could not be resolved. How can I get rid of it?
- it creates `mapOriginAlphabet` slowly. How can I improve it?

I use `gcc 5.3.0`

Here the code: .h file

```
#ifndef TRANSPOSITIONCIPHER_H_
#define TRANSPOSITIONCIPHER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>

#define log(s) std::cout << s << std::endl

class transpositioncipher {
private:
    std::map<char,bool> mapOriginAlphabet;
    std::map<char,char> mapAlphabet;
    std::vector<int> vecOrder;
    std::string mKeySecret;

    std::string removeDuplicates(const std::string strOrigin);
    void createOrder();
    void createSubstitution();

public:
    transpositioncipher(std::string KeySecret);
    virtual ~transpositioncipher();

    std::string encrypt(const std::string strOrigin);
    std::string decrypt(const std::string strOrigin);
    void print();
};

#endif /* TRANSPOSITIONCIPHER_H_ */
```

.cpp file

```
#include "transpositioncipher.h"

transpositioncipher::transpositioncipher(std::string KeySecret) {

    mKeySecret = removeDuplicates(KeySecret);
    createOrder();
    for (int i = 97; i < 123; ++i) {
        char c = (char) i;
        std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(c);
        if (found != std::string::npos) {
            mapOriginAlphabet[c] = false;
        } else {
            mapOriginAlphabet[c] = true;
        }
    }
     createSubstitution();
}

transpositioncipher::~transpositioncipher() {
}

std::string transpositioncipher::removeDuplicates(const std::string strOrigin) {

    std::set<char> moved;
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(strOrigin.size());

    //Only copy one character of each type to the new string
    std::copy_if(std::begin(strOrigin), std::end(strOrigin),
        std::back_inserter(result),
        [&moved](const auto& value) {return moved.insert(value).second;});

     return result;
}

void transpositioncipher::createOrder() {

    std::set<char> chars { mKeySecret.begin(), mKeySecret.end() };

    std::string strTemp = std::string(chars.begin(), chars.end());

    for (auto& x : strTemp) {
        std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(x);

        vecOrder.push_back(found);
    }

}


void transpositioncipher::createSubstitution() {

    int iCols = mKeySecret.length();
    int iRows = 26 / iCols + 1;

    std::vector<std::vector<char>> vecTemp;

    std::vector<char> vecFirstRow;
    for (auto& x : mKeySecret) {
        vecFirstRow.push_back(x);
    }
    vecTemp.push_back(vecFirstRow);

    int index = 97;
    int iNumRow = 0;

    while (iNumRow < iRows) {
        std::vector<char> row;
        int iNumCol = 0;
        while (iNumCol < iCols) {
            if (mapOriginAlphabet[(char) index]) {
                row.push_back((char) index);
                iNumCol++;
            }
            index++;
            if (index > 123) {
                break;
            }
        }
        vecTemp.push_back(row);
        iNumRow++;
    }

    index = 97;
    for (auto& indexCol: vecOrder) {
        for (auto& vec: vecTemp) {
            if (indexCol >= vec.size())
                continue;
            else {
                mapAlphabet[(char)index] = vec.at(indexCol);
                index ++;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::string transpositioncipher::encrypt(const std::string strOrigin) {
    std::string ret;
    for (auto& x: strOrigin) {
        ret += mapAlphabet[x];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please re-insert the first indentation-level, or is that really how your code looks?

Comment: I think you should add some exposition about what this is really intended to accomplish (in reasonable detail, not just "encrypt/decrypt text"). It would not only assist us in analyzing what you're doing, but probably be useful for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Fix the formatting

The code has an inconsistent format, with varying indentation and brace placement.  To make your code easier to read, you should choose a style and apply it consistently.

### Avoid confusing branching constructs

The code currently contains this:

```
for (auto& vec: vecTemp) {
    if (indexCol >= vec.size())
        continue;
    else {
        mapAlphabet[(char)index] = vec.at(indexCol);
        index++;
    }
}
```

(with the formatting fixed).  There are several problems with this.  The first is that the control flow is confusing.  It can be made much simpler:

```
for (auto& vec: vecTemp) {
    if (indexCol < vec.size()) {
        mapAlphabet[(char)index] = vec.at(indexCol);
        index ++;
    }
}
```

### Use appropriate types for variables

The next problem with that code is that it uses an old C-style cast to turn `index` into a `char`.  In fact, it's cast to a `char` just about every time it's used.  Why not just declare it as a `char` in the first place and remove the casts?

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

Instead of using numbers such as `97` and `123` as with this code:

```
for (int i = 97; i < 123; ++i) {
    char c = (char) i;
    std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(c);
```

it would make the code a lot easier to understand if we used the appropriate type of variable and used character constants like this:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
    std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(c);
```

### Use boolean results directly

Rather than this:

```
std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(c);
if (found != std::string::npos) {
    mapOriginAlphabet[c] = false;
} else {
    mapOriginAlphabet[c] = true;
}
```

The code would be much shorter and clearer written like this:

```
bool found = mKeySecret.find(c) != std::string::npos;
mapOriginAlphabet[c] = !found;
```

Or possibly this:

```
mapOriginAlphabet[c] = mKeySecret.find(c) == std::string::npos;
```

### Understand standard template library containers

The code for `encrypt` contains these lines:

```
for (auto& x: strOrigin) {
    ret += mapAlphabet[x];
}
```

This *seems* to do the right thing, but in fact, it inserts non alphabetic characters into the `mapAlphabet` which is *not* the desired behavior here.  Instead, you should use `mapAlphabet.at(x)` like this:

```
for (const auto& x: strOrigin) {
    try {
        ret += mapAlphabet.at(x);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        // ignore out of range inputs
    }
}
```

### Use `const` where practical

Performing an encryption or decryption with a given keyword should not alter the underlying `transpositioncipher` object, so those should be made `const`.

### Prefer `const &` as function arguments

Several of the functions take a `std::string` as an argument, but should probably be `const std::string &` instead to avoid the pointless duplication of a string.  The constructor and `removeDuplicates` are two such places, as are `encrypt` and `decrypt`.

### Re-examine your algorithm

What you have implemented is not a transposition cipher, but a [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) in which the ciphertext alphabet is derived by a transposition.  Encryption and decryption could be done with an inverse pair of [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) objects which may give slightly better performance.

### Don't keep variables that are not needed

The `vecOrder` and `mapOriginAlphabet` variables are only need during object construction, so they should not be permanent data members of the object.  They could be created and destroyed as the `map` is being constructed.  Better yet, don't use them at all, as shown in the next suggestion.

### Rethink your algorithm

Ultimately, the goal of the constructor is to create a substitution `map` based on the keyword.  The procedure is to eliminate duplicate letters in the keyword and then to create a table that includes all of the letters, rearranged according to the keyword.  For example, the keyword "bongo" would be reduced to "bngo" and then your `vecTemp` would look like this:

```
'b', 'o', 'n', 'g', 
'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 
'f', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
'k', 'l', 'm', 'p', 
'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
'y', 'z',
```

We then read down the columns according to the alphabetic order of the letter at the top of each column and create the substitution map:

```
a = b
b = a
c = f
d = k
e = q
f = u
g = y
h = g
i = e
j = j
k = p
l = t
m = x
n = n
o = d
p = i
q = m
r = s
s = w
t = o
u = c
v = h
w = l
x = r
y = v
z = z
```

I think that if you ponder it a while longer, there is perhaps a more direct way to derive the map. Instead, you could start with something like this:

```
std::string &delete_duplicates(std::string &str, size_t len) {
    for (size_t i=0; i < len; ++i) {
        str.erase(std::remove(str.begin()+i+1, str.end(), str[i]),
            str.end());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Then in the constructor, you could have this:

```
delete_duplicates(keyword, keyword.size());
std::string alphabet{keyword + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
delete_duplicates(alphabet, keyword.size());
```

That gives the linear string that represents the two dimensional array shown above. Remap them into vector of strings and sort:

```
std::vector<std::string> columns(keyword.size());
for (size_t i=0, col=0; i < alphabet.size(); ++i) {
    columns[col++] += alphabet[i];
    if (col >= columns.size()) {
        col = 0;
    }
}
std::sort(columns.begin(), columns.end());
// now replace the alphabet
alphabet.clear();
for (auto &word : columns) {
    alphabet += word;
}
```

Now you can construct an encryption map (and a decryption map, if you like) by simply linearly assigning each letter of the "new" alphabet.

Comment: Darn! I have a half-written answer that's now mostly obsolete. Oh well, maybe next time.

Answer (score 3):

#### Choose appropriate data structures

Essentially anywhere a `map<T, bool>` (for some arbitrary type T) can be used, a `set<T>` will probably do the job, unless you really need to differentiate between three states: not present, present but false, and and present and true. I don't think that's the case here though, so `mapOriginalAlphabet` can probably become a `set` (or `unordered_set`).

A `set`, however, is basically just a way of creating a sparse matrix of `bool`. That is, it stores the values for which the `bool` should be `true`. If the set of values is dense (that is, the number used is fairly large in  proportion to the range of possible values) it can make more sense to just store a `vector<bool>` (or, due to the odd specialization on that type, possibly a `deque<bool>` or `vector<char>`, where `char`s are used to store only two values meaning true and false).

In a typical case, this is a trade-off between memory usage and speed. If we store the values densely, we save storage at the expense of extra CPU time. If we store the whole sparse matrix, access is faster but we use extra memory.

In this case, however, the range of values is only the 26 lower-case letters. It's trivial to store the whole sparse matrix in only 26 bytes--less than a sparse matrix is likely to use--so just using an array gives us fast access and fairly minimal memory usage (though if we really cared, we could compress it down to one bit per bool, and store all the values in a 32-bit integer).

#### Include the headers needed for what you use

You haven't included either `<vector>` or `<iterator>` (but you use things that are declared in them).

#### Consider using a namespace

It seems to me that if you're using such things, it would make sense to have a `cipher` namespace, with members like `transposition`, `substitution`, and so on.

```
namespace cipher { 
    class Substitution {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Note: quite a few people do *not* indent members of namespaces. I did here, but it's not really mandatory like *other* indentation is (nudge, nudge).

#### Naming

The Hungarian Notation-like warts on variable names strike me as ugly, and if they're at all useful it's a strong indication of other problems with the code.

#### Use Meaningful Initialization

When at all reasonable, try to initialize things to the value they'll contain, rather than (for example) using default initialization and then putting the required values into them. For example:

```
std::vector<char> vecFirstRow;
for (auto& x : mKeySecret) {
    vecFirstRow.push_back(x);
}
```

...can be written something like:

```
std:vector<char> vecFirstRow{mKeySecret.begin(), mKeySecret.end()};
```

or:

```
std:vector<char> vecFirstRow{ std::begin(mKeySecret), std::end(mKeySecret)};
```

The latter (`std::begin` and `std::end`) is particularly useful for generic code that might receive an array rather than a container that defines `begin` and `end` members.

#### Appropriate Algorithms

This is probably at least part of what you were really asking about.

```
void transpositioncipher::createOrder() {   
    std::set<char> chars{ mKeySecret.begin(), mKeySecret.end() };
    std::string strTemp = std::string(chars.begin(), chars.end());

    for (auto& x : strTemp) {
        std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(x);    
        vecOrder.push_back(found);
    }
}
```

Despite use of a map, this is an \$O(N^2)\$ algorithm. You're creating a collection of the unique characters in the input string, but then doing a linear search in the original string to find the position of each to put into the result.

Instead, I'd build a `map` of the unique characters and their positions in the string, then use that to create the result:

```
void transpositioncipher::createOrder() {
    using T = std::string::size_type;
    std::map<char, T> positions;

    // Note that insert will fail if a character is already present, so this records the
    // position of the first occurrence of each character.
    for (T i = 0; i < mKeySecret.size(); i++)
        positions.insert(std::make_pair(mKeySecret[i], i));

    // Now walk through the characters in alphabetical order and copy their positions
    // To the output.   
    for (auto pos : positions)
        vecOrder.push_back(pos->second);
}
```

Here we depend on the order of a `map` to create the output in the correct order, so we can't use `unordered_map` instead.

There are also a few cases where it *might* be appropriate to consider using a standard algorithm instead of an explicit loop. For one obvious example:

```
std::string ret;
for (auto& x : strOrigin) {
    ret += mapAlphabet[x];
}
```

Could be done as something like:

```
std::transform(strOrigin.begin(), strOrigin.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(ret),
               [&](char c) { return mapAlphabet[c]; });
```

This one is open to a lot of argument though--unless you're quite accustomed to using standard algorithms, it may not be an improvement.

Comment: I think the use of `std::transform`is a good suggestion, but if a map is still used, one would need to use `at` to make the enclosing function `const`.  One could have a single private helper function called by `encrypt` or `decrypt` with an additional argument for which `map` to use making the code quite compact.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to thank you for my learning experience in answering this question. It
required me to do some new research on the internet.

**Inappropriate for Code Review Questions**
It would be better not to include any debugging code in the question, especially
macros in C++11 or C++14. The header file contains the following code that is
not used by the program:

```
#define log(s) std::cout << s << std::endl
```

Including debugging code indicates there are errors in the code. The rules on code
review are that only working code can be included [so debugging code might get the
question put on hold](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

**Indenting Code**
This may be a by product of how the code was entered but the code is almost
unreadable due to the inconsistent nature of indenting.

**MAGIC_NUMBERS**
Raw numeric constants in code are sometimes called [Magic Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) (additional reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))).

This term was coined because anyone reading the code or maintaining the code has no clue
what the number represents. The code is more readable and maintainable if the
numbers are replaced by `symbolic constants`.

The code becomes much more maintainable with `symbolic names` not only because it
is more readable, but if the number has to change it can be changed in only one
place rather than in multiple places in the code.

Examples of Magic Numbers in the code are:
97 (occurs 3 times in the code, no clue what it means)
123 (occurs 2 times in the code, no clue what it means)
26 (occurs once in the code, could mean the number of letters in the alpahbet).

Examples of Symbolic Names for Numeric Constants:

```
constexpr int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;    // [defines ALPHABET_SIZE at compile time][4]
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;        // defines ALPHABET_SIZE at run time.
```

**Default Destructors**
In the header file the code contains

```
    virtual ~transpositioncipher();
```

and in the CPP file the code contains

```
transpositioncipher::~transpositioncipher() {
}
```

Since [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) this can be replaced by a default constructor in the header file

```
    virtual ~transpositioncipher() = default;
```

The compiler will generate any necessary code for the destructor when the default destructor is used.

**Casting in C++**
[Static, Dynamic and reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx) casts are preferred over old style C Casting. Old style C Casting is
not type safe, static and dynamic casts are type safe. Type checking is performed at
compile time for static casts and at run time for dynamic casts.

Use

```
    for (int i = 97; i < 123; ++i) {
        char c = static_cast<char>(i);
```

instead of

```
    for (int i = 97; i < 123; ++i) {
        char c = (char) i;    // Old style C Cast
```

**Use the KISS Programming Principle**
As a suggestion always treat compiler warning messages as compiler errors. A compiler warning message is suggesting that even though the code compiles it may not run properly.

The [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is that code should be kept as simple as possible and not over engineered.

The function below `removeDuplicates()` is overly complicated.
    std::string transpositioncipher::removeDuplicates(const std::string strOrigin) {

```
    std::set<char> moved;
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(strOrigin.size());

    //Only copy one character of each type to the new string
    std::copy_if(std::begin(strOrigin), std::end(strOrigin),
            std::back_inserter(result),
            [&moved](const auto& value) {return moved.insert(value).second;});

    return result;
}
```

The std::set `moved` isn't needed, the condition for the `copy_if()` can and should be defined
in terms of the `result` string. `result.find(value)` will provide the necessary condition.

I believe (sorry, not sure) that part of the warning message is because the code is ignoring the return value from the `copy_if()`. Rather than doing

```
    result.reserve(strOrigin.size());
```

You can use the [return value of copy_if()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) to resize the string after the algorithm is done. This has the benefit of reducing the size of the result to only the contents transferred.

Untested alternate `removeDuplicates()`:

```
std::string transpositioncipher::removeDuplicates(const std::string strOrigin) {
    std::string result;

    //Only copy one character of each type to the new string
    auto it = std::copy_if(std::begin(strOrigin), std::end(strOrigin),
            result.begin(),
            [&result](char value) { return (std::string::npos == result.find(value)); };
    result.resize(std::distance(result.begin(), it);

    return result;
}
```

**Why is My Code Slow**
The number of loops in the following code, and the functions it calls in
all probability contribute to the performance or lack thereof. Keep in
mind that `find()`, `find_if()`, initialization using CONTAINER.begin(), CONTAINER.end() all use loops at some level in their implementation.

```
transpositioncipher::transpositioncipher(std::string KeySecret) {

    mKeySecret = removeDuplicates(KeySecret);
    createOrder();
    for (int i = 97; i < 123; ++i) {
        char c = (char) i;
        std::size_t found = mKeySecret.find(c);
        if (found != std::string::npos) {
            mapOriginAlphabet[c] = false;
        } else {
            mapOriginAlphabet[c] = true;
        }
    }
    createSubstitution();
}
```